# Find text on a string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, filter

i have a problem with jquery condition.

Let me show you the code.

Here i have the "filter" bar:

```
    <div id="filter_menu">

    <label>Filter By:</label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" tags="all">ALL</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" tags="audio" class="filterFunction">audio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" tags="video" class="filterFunction">video</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" tags="other" class="filterFunction">other</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and here my content list that i want to filter by the option in the bar:

```
<ul>
    <li tags="audio video" class="li_item">
       content
    </li>
    <li tags="video" class="li_item">
       content
    </li>
    <li tags="audio" class="li_item">
       content
    </li>
    <li tags="video other" class="li_item">
       content
    </li>
    <li tags="audio other" class="li_item">
       content
    </li>
    <li tags="other" class="li_item">
       content
    </li>
</ul>
```

now there is the jQuery snippet:

```
$(".filterFunction").click(function () {

        categoryFilter = $(this).attr("tags");

        $('.item_li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("tags") == categoryFilter) {
                alert('true');
                }
            else {
                alert('false');
                }
            });

     });
```

HERE THE PROBLEM:
with contents that have more than one "tag" in the attribute tags are never true!
i need a condition that become true when one of the "tag" it's find in the attribute tags!!!

Please someone can help me!!

Thanks a lot!
and sorry for my english :)

Comment: jquery is part of **javascript**, not java. Java is a totally different thing.

Comment: i'm sorry...thank you

Comment: No need to be sorry, its a common misconception, people often think either javascript and java are one in the same.. or jquery is different from javascript. Yes, Java in it of itself is a different language. But jQuery is just a library built off of javascript, to give you the ability to quickly write code, rather then spend a lot of time writing code for every thing like you might traditionally do with javascript example multiple browser hacks, and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an `$.each();` to loop over everything, why not use the tags attribute to select the ones with the key your seeking specifically ie:

```
var my_var = 'other';
$('.li_item[tags*="'+my_var+'"]');
```

Then work with those specifically. There are also multiple selector types to refine the notion of this, view http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp for examples. The above one is one for a wild card match with at least "other" in it. But you can tell it all but, only, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".filterFunction").click(function () {

    categoryFilter = $(this).attr("tags");

    $('.li_item').each(function () {
        var tags = $(this).attr("tags").split(' ');
        if ($.inArray(categoryFilter, tags) > -1) {
            alert($(this).attr("tags") + ': true');
        } else {
            alert($(this).attr("tags") + ': false');
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tba75/)

Comment: thank you very much you save my life. ;)
but i prefer the answer of chris because it's shorter!!!

Comment: @ZimoneIntheJungle it has problems if there are tags like `tags="musicalaudio"` because it will return true for `audio`

Comment: If you tweak the logic for what defines `my_var` from my example, to better suit the needs your going to run into overall, and also tweak the `tags=` for whatever case (seeing as there are multiple selectors that you can avoid the trap of wild carding) You end up saving process by not having to loop, split strings, compare strings to array. Im not saying out the gate my example is an end all solution. But in the long run if you have a lot of `li` for example your going to run into slow down. So my example would be more of a start point